# Long lived GET requests in Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am building a web application on AppEngine python flexible environment that returns a constant stream of output when `GET`tting that given endpoint.

I have set in the `app.yaml`, the timeout parameter in the `gunicorn` command to a sufficiently high value.

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT -t 3600  app:app
```

but after roughly 300 seconds, the client receiving the data receives an incomplete read error, as if the connection was closed:

```
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))
```

I am using `Requests` library and using the `stream=True` option.

From what I can see in [GAE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-handled) in the section of response limits, the limit time is 1 hour, so it should be OK.

Could it be that the Nginx timeout should be set in another parameter?

Comment: Does the server deliver data constantly or could there be a pause between one piece and the next?

Comment: It must be constant. The flask response returns an iterator that constantly returns data. What do you have in mind?

Comment: I thought this could be caused by a long pause between data. However I saw you are using `requests` with `stream=True` and I think it should do the right thing.